# Undefined variable defined, SQL error

Tags: php, mysql

I am setting up a shop that gives instant access to products bought, I get this error that discloses the full path, which is technically a vulnerability. I cannot find the issue. Whenever I do page=item&id[]=1 or page=item&id=1' I get the full path disclosed. The specific error is
  Notice: Undefined variable: file in /home/user/public_html/inc/pages/item.inc.php on line 2
 but I do have the variable defined in another file that extends unto this one. It works perfectly fine. Maybe I could somehow hide the error?

```
    <?php
$related_items = similar_files(safe_sql_str($file['FileName']), $file['FileID'], $file['FileCat'], $file['FilePrice']);
$item_id = (int) safe_sql_str($_GET['id']);

if (!empty($_GET['vote']) && is_numeric($_GET['vote']) && ($_GET['vote'] <= 5) and ($_GET['vote'] >= 1)) {
  if (!isset($_SESSION['voted'][$item_id])) {
    if (apply_vote($item_id, safe_sql_str($_GET['vote']))) {
      $_SESSION['voted'][$item_id] = true;
      $file['FileVotes'] .= ','.$_GET['vote'];
      $vote_str = "<p class='happy_txt'>".LANG('VOTE_SUCCESSFUL')."</p>"; 
    } else {
      $vote_str = "<p class='error_txt'>".LANG('VOTE_DB_ERROR')."</p>"; 
    }
  } else {
    $vote_str = "<p class='error_txt'>".LANG('ALREADY_VOTED')."</p>";
  }
} else {
  $vote_str = '';
}

if(isset($_POST['review'])) {
  $errors['review'] = '';

  if(!is_numeric($_POST['rating']) || ($_POST['rating'] > 5) || ($_POST['rating'] < 1)){
    $errors['review'] .= "<p class='error_txt'>".LANG('INVALID_RATING')."</p>";
  }
  if(strlen($_POST['review']) > 1000){
    $errors['review'] .= "<p class='error_txt'>".LANG('REVIEW_TOO_LONG')."</p>";
  }
  if(strlen($_POST['author']) > 50){
    $errors['review'] .= "<p class='error_txt'>".LANG('NAME_TOO_LONG')."</p>";
  }
  if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0) {
    $errors['review'] .= "<p class='error_txt'>".LANG('BAD_SEC_CODE')."</p>";
  }

  if(empty($errors['review'])) {
    $author = safe_sql_str($_POST['author']);
    $rating = safe_sql_str($_POST['rating']);
    $review = safe_sql_str($_POST['review']);
    if (empty($_SESSION['review'][$item_id])) {
      if (submit_review($item_id, $rating, $author, $review)) {
        $_SESSION['review'][$item_id] = 1;
        $revpage = true;
      }
    } else {
      $errors['review'] .= "<p class='error_txt'>".LANG('ALREADY_REVIEWED')."</p>";
    }
  }
}

if (empty($revpage)) {
  if (!empty($item_id) & is_numeric($item_id)) {
    if (!empty($file) && ($file != 'N/A')) {    
      if ($file['FileActive']) {

        $_SESSION['item_name'][$item_id] = $file['FileName'];
        $_SESSION['item_meth'][$item_id] = $file['FileMethod'];

        if ($file['FileMethod'] === 'download') {
          $_SESSION['item_stock'][$item_id] = 1;
        } elseif ($file['FileMethod'] === 'keys') {
          $_SESSION['item_stock'][$item_id] = 9999;
        } else {
          $_SESSION['item_stock'][$item_id] = $file['FileStock'];
        }

        echo $breadcrumb;
        echo "<h1>".safe_str($file['FileName'])."</h1>\n";
?>
```

Comment: `$file` is not defined. `in another file that extends unto this one` how do you include another file or this file into another one, where `$file` is defined? And this is not an error, but notification, not related to SQL at all. `get the full path disclosed.` production site should log the errors into the file, not output them to visitor. check php.ini file for settings (display_errors, error_log and so on).

Comment: Ok, thanks. and $file = get_file(safe_sql_str($_GET['id']));

Comment: `$file = ` and ... what is next? the file with this line is not included into the listing above, so `$file` is not defined in it. How do you 'transfer' `$file` to the listed code? Translating to russian - каким образом переменная `$file` передается в код выше? этот код подключается в файл, где определяется `$file`? если да, то каким образом?